# AsyncTask doInBackgound() not getting called after reconnection done to WiFi Network

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, android-wifi

In my Activity, there is an AsyncTask that is inside the handler that keeps on running every 1 second to fetch the data from the network ( here WiFI connection is established). This workes properly till the connection is established.

But the problem occurs when my device disconnects to the Wifi Network and again after connection is establised to the same Wifi network, then that AsynckTask's doInBackground does not get called. So, on re-establishment of wifi connection my application is not able to make requests for fetching data.

I have done the re-connection to wifi network call from a background service.

I am posting my code snippet

```
private Runnable liftaxleDataLauncher = new Runnable() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
         public void run() {
               if (getLiftAxledataTask.getStatus() == Status.FINISHED) {
                   Logger.log("Creating new LiftAxle  launcher asyncTask");
                   getLiftAxledataTask = new GetLiftAxleDataTask();
                   getLiftAxledataTask.execute();
               }
               liftAxlePostDataHandler.postDelayed(liftaxleDataLauncher, 1000);
            }
 };
```

Here getLiftAxledataTask.execute() is not letting doInBackground() call after reconnection is established.
Any help or clue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Regards 
Anil Rathore

Comment: Is the logger message being printed out?

Comment: Did you try to put `liftAxlePostDataHandler.postDelayed(liftaxleDataLauncher, 1000);` in a `finally` block ?

Comment: Yes, the Logger message is getting printed. But the log that I have put inside doInBackground of GetLiftAxleDataTask is not getting printed.

Comment: I have tried it after try catch block liftAxlePostDataHandler.postDelayed(liftaxleDataLauncher, 1000);. Will try it in Finally as well.

Comment: Tried in finally as well. But still no luck :(

Comment: I'd think there's a way to see if you are still connected to the internet? Then you'd be able to create a task that checks while you're connected, keep running, on disconnect, retry connection with a new service instance. Something along those lines.